# jQuery adding multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The goal is to add the two classes to any divs with the class `.title`.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#welcome').mouseenter(function() {

      $('.title').addClass('animated').addClass('swing');
    
  });

});
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: that should work

Comment: SO what is the issue?

Comment: Also read the documentation on add class https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Well thanks now I don't feel so bad haha! I have checked my script src that seems to be fine so I'm not sure where I could have gone wrong... @epascarello ill be sure to check it out thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error:

```
$document.ready(function() {   }
```

should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   }
```

If you look in your browser's developer tools, you'll see syntax errors like this in the Console tab.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fb06zxch/)'s a working version.

Comment: Oh damn really haha! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Or, in the modern way: $(function(){})

Answer (score 2):

Add two classes at the same time separated by space

`$('.title').addClass('animated swing')`

Comment: I did try this first time around but I thought that was part of my problem :') Thanks